# how do i assign a property from angular model to a kendo ui datasource

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-grid

I am planning on using kendo ui and angular in a new  asp.net mvc 5 application.

I am trying to figure out how to assign a property from the angular model as the data source of a kendo ui grid.

Answer (score 0):

I found what i was looking for. This code is for auto-complete widget but should work for a grid.

```
    <div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <input kendo-autocomplete k-data-source="dataSource" />
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp", [ "kendo.directives" ]).

    myApp.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
        $scope.dataSource = [
            'foo', 'bar', 'baz'
        ]
    });
</script>
```

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/basics/markup#kendo-ui-angularjs-autocomplete-directive